# Very slow file transfers

Tags: networking

Dual boot with windows, clean install Elementary OS Odin (also tried Horus) network transfer speed 15mbs boot to windows same file on same hard drive transferring to same computer 115mbs
Clean install of Linux mint 98mbs, I would love to use Elementary because it’s so beautiful but this is a deal breaker have tried setting the network to manual 1 gigabit which is what I have, the transfer goes even slower tried disabling ipv6 also no joy.

Comment: Please, how did you measure the rate?